# When do I need the wallet password?

Tags: mist, wallets, password

n00b question here but when do I need my Wallet password? From what I understand you can just copy your Mist-files from one computer to another and without re-entering the password access your wallet.

Do you need the password to sign transactions or something?

Comment: If you forget your ethereum wallet password how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 2):

in short :

You need your password, because your private key is encrypted with.
if you want to send a transaction or to unlock your account you will be asked to provide it, so remember it.

Comment: Ok. So do I need the password each time that I send eth?

Comment: ..and what does unlock mean in this context?